# how to add field for multiple image attachment in openerp module

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I have created a custom openerp module having several fields . I also have a field for attaching image file . But now I need to have a field that should have the ability to attach multiple image fields. How Can I be able to do this?

Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Add a many2many field relating to `ir.attachments`.Check sent by email button in invoice. It opens a wizard which we can add many attachments and also email body

for example, add a many2many field relating to ir.attachement and in xml line of the field, specify widget="many2many_binary"

I dont know whether it is possible to show images as many2many

Comment: Can you give me some hint how this can be done, like will I have to add a many2many field and relate it to my image attachment field